# How to use member functions in an if statement in PHP

Tags: php, class

If I have a function called `name()`, I can check `if (name()) {}`, and if `name()` evaluates to true then the body of the `if` is executed.

But with a class like this:

```
$miniaturas = new miniaturas();
$miniaturas->thumb($db);
```

If I try:

```
if (thumb($miniaturas->thumb($db))) { }
```

Or this:

```
if (thumb($db)) {}
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function thumb() .

How can I call this function in a class like I do for functions outside a class?

Comment: why do you want fn(fn()) ? try if ($miniaturas->thumb($db)) {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just `if ($miniaturas->thumb($db)) { ... }`. This is because you defined `thumb()` as a *member function* to the class `miniaturas`, and because it's a member of that class it's not a member of the global namespace.

Comment: in this case i need to remove $miniaturas->thumb($db); before the if and just execute ($miniaturas->thumb($db)), otherwise i get an error of mysqli. But works now

Comment: Not sure I follow you, but glad you figured it out.

Comment: sorry, i want to say, if i use if ($miniaturas->thumb($db)) {}, i must remove ($miniaturas->thumb($db)) before the if,  or i give an error

Comment: What's the error? Calling class functions in `if` statements is perfectly legal.

Comment: Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli and Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in      -----only occurs  if i execute $miniaturas->thumb($db) and do it again in the if

Answer (score 1):

```
if (thumb($miniaturas->thumb($db))) {}
```

Unless you actually have a function named `thumb` you want

```
if ($miniaturas->thumb($db)) {}
```

The extra function call to thumb is what is breaking

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(function_exists("$miniaturas->thumb"))
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the comment from Neal, the I check for method/function existance using the following php builtin functions:

1. function_exists: I use this one to see if a plain function exists

   if (function_exists('thumb')) {
       thumb($db);
   }
2. method_exists: I prefer to use that one if I have to check for "methods" of objects

   $miniaturas = new miniaturas();

   if (method_exists($miniaturas, 'thumb')) {
       $miniaturas->thumb($db);
   }

In addition to that you also can use is_callable, which checks whether a function/method is callable ... take a look at

[doc for function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

[doc for method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

[doc for is_callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Comment: the method_exists only check if the method exists and not he value of return, correct?

Comment: absolutely correct ... it just checks whether the method does exist on the given class (method_exists('ClassName', 'methodName')) or object (method_exists($object, 'methodName'))
The last one is especially useful for some kind of "duck typing" ... checking for existing methods of an object.

But no method is called. There are various ways to call a function ... but thats another topic :-)

Answer (score 1):

i think you want
if ($miniaturas->thumb($db)) {
    // code
}
and the method thumb should return a boolean

Answer (score 0):

The `function_exists()` function is used to determine whether or not a function exists:

```
if (function_exists('thumb')){
  //...
}
```